# How to detect peak local maxima or blob detection from an image (.png) or a .gif?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

I want to find the peak local maxima from the 2D array rather than image. So, the following script has used to find the local maxima in the 2D array.

```python
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.feature import peak_local_max
from skimage import data, img_as_float

# Input of a 2D array/ 
im = np.real(test_data) 

# Comparison between image_max and im to find the coordinates of local maxima
coordinates = peak_local_max(im, min_distance=8,  num_peaks=2) #, threshold_abs = 0.0004) #
# Display results
#plt.figure()
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(13, 8), sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax = axes.ravel()
ax[0].imshow(im, cmap='seismic')
ax[0].axis('on')
ax[0].set_title('Original')

ax[1].imshow(im, cmap='seismic')
ax[1].autoscale(False)
ax[1].plot( coordinates[:, 1], coordinates[:, 0], 'k.', marker='o', markersize=12)
ax[1].axis('on')
ax[1].set_title('Peak_local_max')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

The "test_data" file is found in this link https://www.file.io/LvDn/download/WqdRCoW2dUPV

This 2D array works fine for me as shown in Fig. 01  [image: Local maxima detected]. The "black spot" detects the local maxima in the 2D array.

However, when I want to detect "local maxima" or "blob detection" from some *.png images or .gif files then I don't detect the local maxima. I've used the following python script but could not succeed as in Fig. 02[image: Local maxima wrongly detected]. The "black spot" wrongly detected the local maxima in the image.  I don't understand how to fix the issue. Can anybody please help?

```html
from PIL import Image
#Reading the image
image = Image.open('sens9.png')
image_gray = image.convert('L')
im = np.array(image_gray) # ndarray
print('IMage shape', im.shape)
```

Comment: I disagree. The maximum value in your images is indeed in the background. You need to define your problem better

Comment: @AnderBiguri, thanks for the comment. When I use 2D array, then its shape is (360,360) but when  I save the image as "sens9.png" and open the .png image  `image = Image.open('sens9.png')..convert('L')` then `image.shape` is (2400, 3900). Can you suggest possible ways how to define the problem better?

Comment: Not sure if you understand. What I mean is not that the image is a different size or anything like that. What I mean is that you are looking for "the highest value in the image", and that is being found. Perhaps you want something else? Also, why do you have images with axes, colorbars etc? Those are only useful for human presentation, why are you trying to find the peaks on there, and not on the raw data (like in the first case)?

Comment: I've a lot of .png/.gif images and I want to detect the highest local maxima/blob detection from the .gif/.png images. I want to know is there any way to find the color or 'blobs' from the images? Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @Alan22 you could segment red color in HSV color space to get your blobs. Did you try that?

Comment: @JeruLuke, from the saved image I can't find the local maximum value [the blobs], however local maxima is found out from the data [not the saved image!]. Do you suggest anything to extract local maxima from image? Thanks

Comment: @Alan22 First segment each blob as individual contours. Iterate through every contour and find its centroid.